# How to use node_module packages correctly

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

So, I'm heading to new territory in web dev.

I set up a basic npm project using `npm init` in my project folder. I don't have angular, react or any other Dev framework running. Basically I want to get started with some npm packages to easily update the things I need.

For my first test I picked bootstrap and font-awesome.

For testing I have a `http-server` running and displaying a index.html file from the public folder.

The site I'm displaying is a basic html site for now. How do I actually implementy packages the right way? Using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/node_modules/...">` is one option but not actually the way it is done, right?

Or will it be repacked once I'm ready for production. Since `node_modules` is not going to be transferred to the prod server.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hey, in most cases you would bundle your frontend dependencies with something like webpack. Including it from node_modules could be a pain, as you are right this folder is normaly not served.

Comment: You should definitely NOT be linking the front-end directly to something in a node_modules directory.  You don't show what it is you're linking to there or why you are so we can't really suggest a better alternative.  If you're using NPM modules in your server implementation, those node_modules directory will still be there in production.  If you're asking asking about bundled client code, then you'll have to describe what it is that you're doing for bundling.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00, I'm currently not in front of the computer. However I was trying to get a basic frontend working. One package I want to use for example is bootstrap. As for the bundling I haven't really tried too many things. I used webpack for a previous project and will look into that a bit more. I was just super confused because I haven't found a real best practices or something like that.

Comment: You're asking a very non-specific and very broad question that I don't think anyone can answer.  There's no single "best practices" for nodejs development.  There are thousands of ways to structure your app and lots of different tools to use.  Deciding among those ways is some combination of specific app requirements, architectural preferences, tools familiarity and then just personal choices.

Answer (score 0):

there is a difference between running javascript in [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/) and the browser javascript engine.

although nodejs is built on top of [v8 javascript engine](https://v8.dev/), nodejs is different in some ways, here are 2 of them:

1. nodejs is used mainly in server-side programming, where javascript is used for client-side
2. nodejs has builtin libraries which are not in the javascript specifications

if you are developing a client-side in nodejs (using `react`, `angular` or any other client-side frameworks), you will have to "convert" (a process called [transpiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler)) it to run within the browser.

there are several tools which can help you in  the process of transpiling your code. some famous ones are [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) and [parcel](https://parceljs.org/) in conjunction with [babel](https://babeljs.io/) (to [pollyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Polyfill)) to "build" your project and yield a bundled (few javascript file, usually one, that bundles all the javascript code into one of more files) javascript file(s), which are loaded by the webpage.

as you can see, once the project is bundled, `node_modules` directory has no use -- exactly what you want.